# Training algorithm for Manual error correction in text

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language-processing

I want to work on a model where I make some manual corrections in my clinical notes data and want the neural network to learn those corrections.The algorithm will be supplied with both corrected and initial documents for supervised learning.

I am now looking for some survey or research papers to start with. I have searched and downloaded tens of articles but none of them seems related.

I would appreciate if someone could provide a few good starting points (papers, books).

also I suspect that I am not using the correct keywords for my search. I'll appreciate if you could also suggest suitable search keywords.